# Delete records in snowflake for a particular value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to delete rows which contains nan but unable to do so:
It is just a sample data ,actual table has 20k records with lots of columns.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'abc' |
| 1 | nan |
| 2 | 'efg' |
| 2 | nan |

I had tried using :

```
delete from table  where value='nan' 
delete from table where upper(value)=upper('nan')
delete from table where value=trim('nan')
delete from table where value in ('nan')

combinations of all above.
```

Still nan is appearing in dataset.

Comment: nan, as on not a number? Or the string value nan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE TRIM(value) = 'nan';
```

or use like query :

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE value LIKE 'nan%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE FROM sales
WHERE status = 'Cancelled';
```

Explanation:

The `DELETE FROM` statement is used to delete records from a table.
The `sales` is the table name.
The `WHERE` clause is used to specify the condition for deletion. In this case, we're targeting records where the `status` column has the value `Cancelled`.